# Problem creating dll and loading then in Python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, dll, codeblocks, ctypes

I want to learn to create  DLLs in c++ and use them in python to increase the speed of calculations. To begin with, I tried to create a simple C++ dll and load it in Python using ctypes, but I get OSError: [WinError 126]:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/unknown/Documents/Work_Pyth/tests/test.py", line 4, in <module> lib = CDLL("tdll.dll") File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36\lib\ctypes_init_.py", line 348, in init self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module was not found
```

DLL code **main.h**

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__
#include <windows.h>
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
extern "C" void DLL_EXPORT fun(double* in,long len);
#endif
```

DLL code **main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"
double * v;
extern "C" void DLL_EXPORT fun(double* in,long len)
{
    v=new double[len];
    for (long ii=0; ii<len; ii+=1){
        v[ii]=ii;
    }
    for (long ii=0; ii<len; ii+=1){
        in[ii]=v[ii];
    }
    delete v;
}
extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

In real code the DLL will need to use temporary arrays, so the test DLL contains an intermediate array v. I compile DLL using CodeBlocks with mingw:

```
-------------- Build: Release in tdll (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -fPIC -O -Wall -fPIC -DBUILD_DLL -O -fPIC  -c C:\Users\unknown\Documents\Work_Cpp\tdll\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
```

**How do i use the DLL, Python code**

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

lib = CDLL("tdll.dll")
len=5
v=np.zeros(len)
print(v)
lib.fun.restype=c_void_p
lib.fun.argtypes=(np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64),  c_long)
lib.fun(v,len)
print(v)
```

Why does the error OSError: [WinError 126] occur? I don't think it can be caused by dependencies. Is it possible to use `new` and `delete` operators in DLL code? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: i know windows version of python needs pyd binaries compiled with msvc, not MinGW, however i am not exactly sure about DLLs, so it may or may not be the cause.

Comment: i'd also make sure you are compiling 64-bit version of the dll, by adding -m64 to the MinGW arguments.

Comment: I compiled the 64-bit version of the dll with -m64 and the program still doesn't work.

Comment: The error doesn't occur if I directly fill the array "in" without using the intermediate array "v". Why does the error occur if I use an intermediate array "v"?

Comment: maybe it's because 'new' is implemented in the libstdc++.dll, so it's a dependency, use a dependency walker to check, search the internet for "dependency walker windows"

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is a dependency on libstdc++-6.dll. I added the -static flag to the linker, and this dependency was gone. Thank you for help!

Comment: Please, next time, search for the error message. I've seen 126 so often that I don't even need to look up its meaning, many times of those in questions here even.

Comment: FYI, use `None` for a return type of `void`.  `c_void_p` is for `void*`.

Comment: If having additional info, add it in the question rather than in comments. Please also paste the link command.